# How Arrays.sort function works?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am new to java programming and i am trying to sort arrays using **Arrays.sort()** function. After using **Arrays.sort(array)**,I am printing the final sorted array.

For example:

Input : **1 3 2 4**

Output comes as :  **0 0 0 0**.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class TestClass {
     public static final int MAX_SIZE = 20;
     public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n,temp,count;
        int[] array = new int[MAX_SIZE]; 
        n = input.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i) {
          array[i] = input.nextInt(); 
        }
       Arrays.sort(array);
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i) {
          System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have initialized you array to hold 20 integers but you input only 5. Hence the first 15 elements will be 0 followed by the numbers you have inputted once the array is sorted.

To fix the issue you can initialize the array with `n` instead of `MAX_SIZE` as shown below:-

```
n = input.nextInt();
int[] array = new int[n];
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the size of the array to match what your input should be, not to the maximum allowed size:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static final int MAX_SIZE = 20;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n, temp, count;

        n = input.nextInt();
        if (n > MAX_SIZE) {
            //handle error somehow
        }
        int[] array = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        Arrays.sort(array);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Posted a bit too late I see. Oh well, you should accept Nicholas's answer @Ayush

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize an array in Java it gets default value of `0` for primitive `int`:

```
int[] array = new int[MAX_SIZE];
```

The fact that you are not seeing your desired input of `1,2,3,4` is a separate problem with your `Scanner` code.